# How to handle code changes after submitting for code review

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, alm

In my current team we do code reviews before each check in using Visual Studio 2012 and TFS. However while code review is pending you might do some changes to your code.
So when the code review comes back you want to check in only code which was peer reviewed (without non pear reviewed changes).

What is the best way to do it?

Currently before check in I suspend changes and get a peer reviewed change set, check it in and then resume work. Is there a better way of doing it?